# The Microsoft Bing Map control did not get re-rendered while adding it to the scroll viewer and restoring the window

Tags: wpf, maps, wpf-controls, bing-maps

When adding the Microsoft Bing Map control inside the ScrollViewer, in the initial load the map will render in the whole available window size and when we maximize the window, the map will be rendered for the new available size, it is fine. If we again restore the window size, then the map is not re-rendered for the new available size instead the ScrollViewer scroll bars will be enabled. Also, this happens only when setting the VerticalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to "Auto".

The code snippet is provided below:

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="0"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Grid>
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="Add Bing map Key"
           Center="47.620574,-122.34942"
           ZoomLevel="4"></m:Map>
</Grid></ScrollViewer>
```

**Output Screenshot:**

**Initial Load**

[image: Initial Load]

**After maximizing and restoring the window**

[image: After Maximizing and restoring the window]

Anyone please help me to re-render the Map when restoring the window after maximized it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you put it in a ScrollViewer at all?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the Bing Maps USP map control instead of the legacy WPF control. The WPF control has very limited functionality and is no longer supported. The UWP control is actively maintained and can be used in WPF apps via a XAML island. It has a lot more features and functionalities as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands